# Initializing multiple vals in a trait using a single database session

Tags: scala, initialization

We have several traits whose fields are initialized from a database ([Slick](http://slick.typesafe.com/) on top of MySql), e.g.

```
trait MyTrait {
  val field1 = db withSession { Table1.get(id1) }
  val field2 = db withSession { Table2.get(id2) }
  val field3 = db withSession { Table3.get(id3) }
  ...
}
```

and I'd like to be able to initialize them with a single session.  I could do something like

```
trait MyTrait {
  private val tuple = db withSession { Table1.get(id1) -> Table2.get(id2) -> Table3.get(id3) }
  val field1 = tuple._1
  val field2 = tuple._2
  val field3 = tuple._3
}
```

but I was hoping to do it with less boilerplate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should also work? (you probably could also retrieve all 3 ids in a single query...)

```
private val (field1, field2, field3) = db withSession { 
  Table1.get(id1) -> Table2.get(id2) -> Table3.get(id3) 
}
```